# Issue in passing date in postman and receiving the date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I'm facing a strange problem but can't figure out is it postman issue or SQL Server issue or NodeJS issue.

- passing “DOB”: “01/01/1990” from JSON
- getting 1989-12-31 18:30:00.000 in SQL Server

Can anyone help me I? I am not able to find proper reason and solution for this. Just to mention that I am using datetime datatype to receive it in SQL Server.

The difference is 5:30 minutes which is my current timezone

Tried using datetime offset datatype tried to convert date in UTC format with the help of moment.

Comment: Debug it, step through every step and work out at which point it doesn't work as you wish.

Comment: date is changed as soon as data is passed to sql server

Comment: So you have debugged in in Node, and watched Node take the JSON and send it correctly to SQL and then it end up wrong? If so, show the code doing the update. And remove the postman tag as its no relevant.

Comment: You mean 5:30 *hours* right?

Comment: yes 5horus 30 min

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and support especialy Dale. your comments made me look at the code once again but with a fresh mind. As of now the job is done , but its not a perfect solution. I am still looking for a valid answer.                                The problem was in defining the variable ( i still not consider it as a solution) that was a hit and try.                  Earlier i was  passing the DOB variable as datetime, but now i am using .input("DOB", sql.VarChar(20), DOB) earlier it was .input("DOB", sql.DateTime, DOB)

Comment: That's definitely not a good solution, you should always be using the correct data types. And as I said in order to get any assistance you need to post your code

Comment: I've never used NodeJS but I believe it runs on JavaScript, and in JS a Date object always includes timezone info. If you don't want that you'll have to adjust it to compensate.

Comment: async function updatecpinfo(cpinfo) {
  try {
    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let updateResult = await pool
      .request()
      .input("DOB", sql.VarChar(20), cpinfo.DOB)                                                                             .execute("StoreProcedureName");                                                                              return updateResult.recordset;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err); // Log the complete error stack trace
    throw err;
  }
}

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into your question.